# Wiimote configuration ... and pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi2, wiimote

I finally took my raspberry pi 2 and as a retro like… installing the retropie.. btw excellent…

All is ok except the connections of the wiimote…

I do everything letter by letter guide from this page https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Wiimotes-with-classic-controllers and use the dirty way…

The wiimote register just fine but after that i take warning that “warning duplicate absolute axis assignment: two times…

I try everything and search but with no luck…

Anyone can help me…

Thank you